# Select Mysql retornar os total de dias trabalhados por mês?

Tags: mysql, select, group-by

Tenho uma tabela: PACIENTES onde o usuário cadastra os pacientes do dia, sabendo disso, se esse usuário cadastra pelo menos 1 paciente no respectivo dia então significa que ele trabalhou nesse dia correspondente.

Tabela PACIENTE:
id | Nome_Paciente | data_Cadastro (data_time)

Eu já tenho um SQL onde mostrar o total de paciente separados em cada mês.
A duvida é como posso usar esse mesmo Select, para retornar também o total de dias trabalhados? (tipo um segundo GroupBy com o total de dia trabalhados em cada mês)

O select usado Atualmente retorna o valor Abaixo:

```
SELECT MONTH(data_Cadastro) mes, YEAR(data_Cadastro) ano, COUNT(id) total FROM paciente WHERE data_Cadastro >= DATE('2022-01-01 00:00:00') GROUP BY YEAR(data_Cadastro), MONTH(data_Cadastro);
```

Retorna:

```
mes | ano   | Total Paciente por ID 
03  | 2022  | 18
04  | 2022  | 25
05  | 2022  | 37
07  | 2022  | 30
```

Como eu gostaria de Exibir o Relatório:

Exibir também o total de dias trabalhados no mês correspondente, Exemplo abaixo:

```
mes | ano   | Total Paciente por ID | Total Dias Trabalhados no Mês 
03  | 2022  | 18                    | 10
04  | 2022  | 25                    | 20
05  | 2022  | 37                    | XX...
07  | 2022  | 30                    | YY... etc.
```

Comment: Se eu entendi corretamente a estrutura de sua tabela, você poderia fazer um count distinct por dia. Ficaria assim: COUNT(DISTINCT DAY(data_Cadastro)) as total_dias_trabalhados

Comment: Perfeito isso mesmo, Obrigado